# How to make a UI like this ...?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, shapes

Hello every one actually my question is how to make a UI in XML with the shapes like this which is present in the Image ...!!

this is image which is generated in the Photoshop, i want to make the same interface in the Android XML.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use an `ImageView` and use that image as `android:src`

Comment: You can make the sawtooth part a **tile** (in the shape of an **M**) and repeat it horizontally (so to get something like **MMMMMMMMM**). The rest, is just  a color.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to set that image as the background of your layout. You could convert your image into a nine-patch if you don't want the jagged part to scale.